# How to save newly added data in a row or rows from DataGridView  into SQL Server when the user clicks a button

Tags: vb.net, t-sql

I'd be grateful if could modify the following code for me so that it save data row by row from a DataGridView into SQl Server. Currently, the code saves data from all rows at time instead of saving only the recently added data in a row or rows when the user clicks a button.

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Try
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To dgMarksEntry.Rows.Count - 1
                If dgMarksEntry.Item(1, i).Value = "" Then
                Else
                    qry = "insert into StudentDetails.MarksEntry values ('" & dgMarksEntry.Item(0, i).Value & "', '" & dgMarksEntry.Item(2, i).Value & "','" & dgMarksEntry.Item(3, i).Value & "','" & dgMarksEntry.Item(4, i).Value & "') "
                    cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Insert Error: " & ex.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
        MessageBox.Show("Record successfully saved", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Comment: Remember to format code snippets to improve readability of your question.

Comment: When should these new rows be stored to db? Immediately when they were created, which would result in an emty row to be stored or when the current row was changed, which would need you to handle updates to existing rows as well or when the user hits a button, which would need you to track new rows since last call. Not quite sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: I mean the newly added data in a row or rows should be saved  when the user clicks a button.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep track of the row indexes in a separate event such as the rowsadded event. Then in your loop, only execute the sql command if "i" matches a row index that you kept track of. Then clear the array (or whichever method you use) after the loop has finished.